# Trying to reverse an equation and solve for a different variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My original question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307667/creating-an-application-with-a-level-system-and-i-would-like-to-convert-the-valu) produced this equation:

$$\text{level} = \operatorname{int}\left(\left(\left(\sqrt{\text{xp}\times 8 + 100}\over10\right)-1\right)\div2\right)$$

Now I would like to reverse the variables and solver for xp instead of level.

Sorry about the equation formatting, I'm new to MathJax.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By "int," do you mean the `floor`/"greatest integer" function?  Or do you mean to round to the nearest integer? (Edit: nice job on MathJax, btw--it can be tough to get the hang of, but we *really* appreciate it when someone actually does go to the effort to learn some like you did. `:)`)

Comment: @anorton thanks on the MathJax, I had to look around but I found what I needed :). The "int" is as in programming and will strip off any remainder so there's no issue there for me.

Comment: Oops, I had to look again. The "int" is for the whole equation.

Comment: Well, technically you can't reverse it, since because of the floor function many different xps will give the same level. But you can find out the minimum xp required to reach each level (I'm assuming this is for a game).

Comment: @JavierBadia Yes you are correct and yes I am looking for the min xp to reach a level. I didn't realize that until you pointed it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the int,
you cannot exactly solve for $xp$.
However, you can give the range of
$xp$ values that can produce $level$.

Let's take your original equation
(reformatted to make me feel better):
$level = int\left(\left(\left(\sqrt{xp\times 8 + 100}\over10\right)-1\right)\div2\right)$.

I'll extract the inside function:
$L = \left(\left(\sqrt{xp\times 8 + 100}\over10\right)-1\right)\div2$,
so
$level = int(L)$.

Then,
showing each step,

$\begin{align}
2L &= \left(\sqrt{xp\times 8 + 100}\over10\right)-1\\
10(2L+1) &= \sqrt{xp\times 8 + 100}\\
(10(2L+1))^2 &= xp\times 8 + 100\\
\dfrac{(10(2L+1))^2-100}{8} &= xp\\
\end{align}
$

For $L \ge 0$,
the left-hand expression is strictly increasing.
Call it $xpl$,
so
$xpl(L) = \dfrac{(10(2L+1))^2-100}{8}$.

Since $level = int(L)$,
$level \le L < level+1$
.

Therefore
$xpl(level) \le xpl(L) < xpl(level+1)$
so,
since $xp = xpl(L)$,
$xpl(level) \le xp < xpl(level+1)$
.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Excellent work.