# Trying to reverse an equation for levelling system

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to reverse this function to get the Level from the exp given in this equation.

```
(Level^1.7)/Level*60

Input: 5569xp
Expected output: 19
```

I've tried a few things but can't seem to get my head around them, so if possible I would also like it to explain how you reverse an exponent.

The best i've come up with

$$ \log1.7\left(5569\right)\cdot\frac{5569}{60} $$
But this equals 5.9438

I've looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458777/trying-to-reverse-an-equation-and-solve-for-a-different-variable) question but it's gone straight over my head

Comment: `(level^1.7)/level` is just `level^0.7`.

Comment: if $x=a L^c$, then $(x/a)^{1/c} = L$

Comment: OK, here is my guess: At each level, that formula tells you the amount of experience you need to go up to the next level (the 60 is above / to the right of the fraction). So to get to level 5, you need a total of $$\frac{1^{1.7}}{1}\cdot 60 + \frac{2^{1.7}}{2}\cdot 60 + \frac{3^{1.7}}{3}\cdot 60 + \frac{4^{1.7}}{4}\cdot 60\approx 445$$experience points. You want to know which level you are at after a given amount of total experience points. How am I doing?

Comment: Ah yes, I think I was a little confused myself...
Turns out that I'm trying to figure out the cumulative XP (this is for a game)
The value 471 is the xp difference between L 19 & 20
E.g L 19 minimum is 5544 & to get to level 20 you need + 471 -> 6032

Comment: This might help [imgur link](https://imgur.com/a/ddOgVAb)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I understood so far. You have a function called Required XP for a level,
$$
r(L) =
\left\{
\begin{split}
48,&~\text{if}~L=0 \\
 60 \cdot L^{0.7},& \text{otherwise}
\end{split}
\right.
$$
(This is actually the amount of XP points required to move from level $L-1$ to level $L$, but for the math part this is not important). This function produces non-integers, so actually you need to round to the nearest integer. For the purposes of this analysis, this rounding is ignored. I don't think it would affect the results significantly.

We have another function, which is the cumulative XP points to get to level $L$. This is simply the sum of all the values of $r(l)$ for $l=0,1,2, \ldots L$.
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
C(L) 
&= r(0) + r(1) + \ldots + r(L) \\
&= 48 + 60\cdot 1^{0.7} + 60\cdot 2^{0.7} + \ldots + 60\cdot L^{0.7} \\
&= 48 + 60\cdot \left( 1^{0.7} + 2^{0.7} + \ldots + L^{0.7} \right) \\
\end{array}
$$
**Approach 1**

The expression in the parenthesis is a slightly tricky expression. Just considering the sum of powers
$$
S_p(L) = \sum_{k=1}^L k^p
$$
gives us an analytical solution
$$
S_p(L) = \zeta(-p) - \zeta(-p,1+L)
$$
where $\zeta(z)$ is the Riemann zeta function, $\zeta(z;a)$ is the Hurwitz zeta function. Sounds like a headache. We could calculate
$$
\zeta(-0.7) \approx -0.146~237 \ldots
$$
but I seriously doubt that you would want to dabble with a Hurwitz zeta function. For this reason, I would suggest that you try a numerical approach instead and forget all about these complications.

**Approach 2**

If we assume that you're mostly interested in values of $L\leq 100$, then a reasonable approximation for $C(L)$ is
$$
C(L) \approx (6.7202) L^2 + (239.498) L + (-1054.58) 
$$
From which you can approximately solve $L$:
$$
 (6.7202) L^2 + (239.498) L + (-1054.58 - C(L)) = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
L \approx \frac{-(239.498) + \sqrt{(239.498)^2 - 4(6.7202)(-1054.58 - C(L))}}{2(6.7202)}
$$
A numerical example, let's say that you have cumulative XP points $C(L) = 50~000$. Then we get
$$
L \approx \frac{-(239.498) + \sqrt{(239.498)^2 - 4(6.7202)(-1054.58 - 50~000)}}{2(6.7202)}
\approx 71.1
$$
So that should be enough for level $71$. Due to the inaccuracies produced in the first step and the approximation for $C(L)$, there is some degree of numerical inaccuracy. In this case, the correct value should be $70$.